# How do you split action into multiple action in react redux?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have an api that give my react app data

```
{
    "data_for_action1": ...
    "data_for_action2": ...
    "data_for_action3": ...
}
```

To propagate the data through redux I can

```
this.props.reduxAction1({
    "data_for_action1": ....
})
this.props.reduxAction2({
    "data_for_action2": ....
})
this.props.reduxAction3({
    "data_for_action3": ....
})

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  { reduxAction1, reduxAction2, reduxAction3 }
)(MyComponent);
```

Call all redux action successively, but the problem is that I have to do this for all component that use this api.

Is there a way to split this in `action function` instead

```
export const myCombineReduxAction = myInfo => {
    // call reduxAction1, reduxAction2, and reduxAction3
}
```

instead of

```
  export const reduxAction1 = myInfo => ({
    type: ActionType1,
    payload: { myInfo }
  });

  export const reduxAction2 = myInfo => ({
    type: ActionType2,
    payload: { myInfo }
  });


  export const reduxAction3 = myInfo => ({
    type: ActionType3,
    payload: { myInfo }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

I think so:-

You could create a **custom** `function` in your `reducer`:

- given if all your `action` use the **same** `dispatch` from the **same** `reducer`
- `args` or `props` passed to the **custom** `function` could be **anything**. But a make sure to **pass** the `dispatch` too
- in `reducer`:-

```js
export const myCombineReduxAction = (dispatch, myInfo) => {
  // then run whatever dispatch here
  dispatch({
    type: ActionType1,
    payload: { myInfo }
  })
  dispatch({
    type: ActionType2,
    payload: { myInfo }
  })
  dispatch({
    type: ActionType2,
    payload: { myInfo }
  })
}
```

- in `demo` component:-

```js
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { myCombineReduxAction } from "../redux/reducer/whateverReducer";
const Demo = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const getData = () => {
    const myInfo = 'something'
    myCombineReduxAction(dispatch, myInfo)
  }

  return (<>Something</>)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use thunk you can do the following:

```
export const myCombineReduxAction = (myInfo) => (
  dispatch
) => {
  dispatch(reduxAction1(myInfo));
  dispatch(reduxAction2(myInfo));
  dispatch(reduxAction3(myInfo));
};
```